# Battery drains fast when it is suspended

Tags: 14.04, suspend, battery

I installed Ubuntu MATE 14.04 around a weak ago, and have had some problems.

When I suspend the computer, it still drains battery faster than I think is correct. The battery is supposed to last around 8,5 hours, and after around 7 hours of suspending with almost full battery, it still turns of.

I just checked for updates and installed them.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if the computer don't actually suspend correctly. This is because I have also noticed that when it is in suspend, in the case and in the backpack, it is warm when I pick it up. Not so warm that it is uncomfortable, and the fan doesn't work hard, I think, since it is not making any noise. But it is warmer than I think it should be, and i do not like it. Any thoughts?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072066/sleep-mode-drains-battery-very-fast/1085901#1085901

Comment: This may be your fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1036122#1036122