# Laptop won't wake after updating to 18.04

Tags: suspend, 18.04, thinkpad

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. Since the upgrade, my laptop sometimes won't wake up after being suspended (usually after it has been suspended for longer). When I open the lid, no lights go on. Pushing the power button does not cause the laptop to resume. I am forced to hold the power button for 10s to force a shutdown and then boot.

This laptop doesn't have a discrete graphics card so that is not the issue here.

My laptop is a ThinkPad X1 carbon gen 5.

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-22-generic
```

Comment: It's about a different machine but the same symptoms, so possibly a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1044270. Follow the solutions to see if it's an s2idle problem and if not then you can try using an older kernel and let the bug report know if that's the only fix that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the diagnosis there and it looks like my laptop is entering deep sleep. However, the problem hasn't reoccurred too recently so it is possible that this was an s2idle issue which was fixed by some update. Since this issue was only itermittent I want to wait and see if it comes back or not.