# Black screen with repeating wall of text when waking from suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend

Almost every time I open my Lenovo Y720 laptop's lid I get a black screen with an `incomplete report` wall of text that keeps scrolling endlessly. Sometimes it stops after a couple of seconds and continues to the login screen. I have tried multiple reinstalls, but nothing changes.

`incomplete report` wall of text:

```
[ 4261.183306] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.184539] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.187337] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.187402] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.188223] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.188952] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.189947] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.192531] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.194762] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.195891] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.197419] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.198935] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.201199] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.204554] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.204676] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.212447] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.213026] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.213327] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.214222] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.216710] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.218163] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.224759] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.225843] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.226430] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.229406] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.230288] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.231922] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.232182] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.236208] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.239205] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.243521] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.244568] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.245057] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.248054] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.254883] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.255598] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.255923] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.256387] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.257311] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.258572] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.263791] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.264204] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.264798] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.266089] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.266607] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.266760] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.266828] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.267650] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.270514] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.273779] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.275884] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.280526] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.281542] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.281830] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.282742] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.284003] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.284127] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.285439] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.293307] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.293726] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
[ 4261.295128] i2c_hid i2c-ITE:3301:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)
```

Comment: I'm entirely guessing about this but it might be good to be able to rule it out - I'm guessing that this 'get_input' thing might have something to do with the laptop lid switch. To check this, please try to manually suspend your laptop without closing or opening the lid and see if the behaviour is the same. (On Gnome 'suspend' is slightly hidden but pressing the 'super' key and typing 'suspend' works also.)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The same wall of text comes up this way too, although I tried multiple times and it was a lot shorter than closing the lit.

Comment: Hi - just found an interesting thing after searching for "i2c-ITE33D1:00" - it came up in a google groups chat about touchscreen issues - does your Lenovo have a touchscreen? Not got any clue how to fix it, but it might help in diagnosing where things are going wrong.

Comment: Nope no touchscreen. Thank you for still trying to look into this though!

Comment: No problem - I'd experienced a suspend issue on one machine (3 others tested have no problems) with Ubuntu & Kubuntu 18.04 and finally tracked it down to a kernel problem and started a bug report. I've been trying to point anyone experiencing similar suspend problems towards some troubleshooting steps but haven't seen this 'wall of text' issue before. It's probably not related but if you're curious to see if any of the steps help you could take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1044270#1044270

Comment: The steps are mainly - is it a nVidia problem?, is it an s2idle problem? & does using an older kernel fix the issue? I'm wondering whether any of these are affecting your machine but not quite causing the full 'seize up and needing a hard reset' issue but give a 'wall of text' instead.

Comment: I have deep sleep so it is not that. I don't think it's an older kernel since it was the same problem under ubuntu 16 and 17.

Comment: Ah, possibly it might be related to nVidia graphics but I've not really had any experience of nVidia issues apart from seeing the nouveau.modeset=0 helping some folks with suspend issues. The specs for the Y720 say it has nVidia graphics so hopefully there might be something useful here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers . Sorry I've not been much help!

Comment: You have been of much help, thank you! I will give this a try, if it doesn't work I think I will just ignore it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalling the system a lot of times, rebooting after installing each and every program / adding a ppa / any kind of change in the system, i finally know the reason for this. It is plain and simply the Nvidia driver. If I uninstall everything Nvidia related, this does not show up anymore. As soon as I install Nvidia drivers, this happens. Thanks Nvidia.

Comment: I'm uncertain if there's any problem with your Nvidia driver. I think that's a symptom of the problem, not the cause of it, and the real problem is with the gdm3 package. I haven't seen that error message before, so I'm not sure though. For more information please read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot/1037192#1037192). I might have tried to answer this question before, but I'm late to the party and I just read it.