# Ubuntu hp probook suspend problem

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I recently bought a new laptop (an hp probook 450 G5), and installed ubuntu 18.04 on it.

But i have a big issue, when i close my laptop or press the power button to suspend, it won't resume when i want to come back. I just have a black screen.

I updated the kernel, intel-microcode is uninstalled, and this issue is still here and haven't found any solution on internet.

So please, can someone help me?

Comment: Different machine but similar issue - possibly a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1044270 Please have a look at the fixes - I've put an answer that has some steps to check suspend functions at all, and then: 1. Is it Nvidia? 2. Is it s2idle? 3. Does installing a 4.14 kernel fix it?

Comment: I've also started a thread for collecting 'suspend on 18.04 issues' together for further discussion: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395562&p=13780724#post13780724