# CMOS checksum error and BIOS reset upon waking from suspend (HP Stream 14)

Tags: suspend, bios, secure-boot, stream, checksums

first post/first time asking anything in any forum ever!

The only other existing post about my issue ( [Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Stream 14 - Suspend Produces Checksum Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060310/ubuntu-18-04-on-hp-stream-14-suspend-produces-checksum-error) ) doesn't help much. :(

I'm running Xubuntu 18.04.01 LTS on an HP Stream 14 (14-CB108CA). The CMOS battery is practically BRAND NEW.

After disabling Secure Boot, everything works absolutely perfectly with this computer EXCEPT:

If I put the computer to sleep, upon waking it, I'll get a "CMOS checksum error," which'll cause the BIOS to reset immediately (Secure Boot = Enabled is the default value it resets to), which'll cause the BIOS to not detect my boot drive whatsoever, so I need to go to the BIOS and disable Secure Boot again after force shutting the machine down from its error state.

This error only occurs after waking from suspend.

I know there are a lot of known suspend issues, but this is not one of them, I believe... I've been remedying suspend issues on other Linux machines for the past 5 years, but have never seen anything that literally throws a CMOS error and resets your BIOS...!

Thanks in advance!
sshaverd