# black/purple screen after wake up

Tags: 18.04, asus

Since my last update my screen stays black when it wakes up for suspend mode. I am running 18.04 on Asus UX433F. Currently using Kernel 4.19.11 because of sound issue (see article: [No Sound in ASUS ZenBook 14 UX433FN after installing ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098262/no-sound-in-asus-zenbook-14-ux433fn-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04)) and suspects this might be the issue again.

Here's my upgrade logs:

```
2019-05-22 08:02:33 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 74.0.3729.131-1 74.0.3729.157-1
2019-05-22 08:02:37 upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:18.04.31 1:18.04.32
2019-05-22 08:02:37 upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:18.04.31 1:18.04.32
2019-05-22 08:02:37 upgrade python3-distupgrade:all 1:18.04.31 1:18.04.32
2019-05-22 08:02:37 upgrade libnm0:amd64 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1 1.10.14-0ubuntu2
2019-05-22 08:02:37 upgrade gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1 1.10.14-0ubuntu2
2019-05-22 08:02:37 upgrade libmbim-proxy:amd64 1.14.2-2.1ubuntu1 1.18.0-1~ubuntu18.04.1
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade libmbim-glib4:amd64 1.14.2-2.1ubuntu1 1.18.0-1~ubuntu18.04.1
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade libmm-glib0:amd64 1.6.8-2ubuntu1 1.10.0-1~ubuntu18.04.2
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade libnm-util2:amd64 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1 1.10.14-0ubuntu2
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade libnm-glib4:amd64 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1 1.10.14-0ubuntu2
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade libqmi-proxy:amd64 1.18.0-3ubuntu1 1.22.0-1.2~ubuntu18.04.1
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade libqmi-glib5:amd64 1.18.0-3ubuntu1 1.22.0-1.2~ubuntu18.04.1
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade modemmanager:amd64 1.6.8-2ubuntu1 1.10.0-1~ubuntu18.04.2
2019-05-22 08:02:38 upgrade network-manager:amd64 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1 1.10.14-0ubuntu2
2019-05-22 08:02:39 upgrade network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu:all 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1 1.10.14-0ubuntu2
2019-05-23 06:39:04 upgrade firefox:amd64 66.0.5+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 67.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-05-23 06:39:10 upgrade firefox-locale-en:amd64 66.0.5+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 67.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-05-23 06:39:13 upgrade intel-microcode:amd64 3.20190514.0ubuntu0.18.04.2 3.20190514.0ubuntu0.18.04.3
2019-05-23 06:39:24 upgrade libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7
2019-05-23 06:39:27 upgrade libraw16:amd64 0.18.8-1ubuntu0.2 0.18.8-1ubuntu0.3
2019-05-23 06:39:30 upgrade python3-urllib3:all 1.22-1 1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-05-23 06:39:33 upgrade curl:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7
2019-05-23 06:39:33 upgrade libcurl4:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7
2019-05-23 06:39:37 upgrade gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 2.24.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-05-23 06:39:37 upgrade gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 2.24.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-05-23 06:39:40 upgrade libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 2.24.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-05-23 06:39:41 upgrade libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 2.24.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

Comment: i don't want to upgrade at this stage, prefer the lts version for now. what laptop model are you using? @tatsu

Comment: yeah thats another issue I am having, the cursor is jumping when I am using the trackpad, tried some suggested solutions but just can't get it working. ok so upgrading would be the best option then. what kernel you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer on the following thread: [Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates)

The reason why it is stuck on the purple/black screen is because of the microcode update. I have not tried to downgrade intel-microcode package on 19.04 but I can confirm if works on 18.04. The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an a bug in `microcode_ctl` . This is a package which contains both processor ‘microcode’ updates and a loader for such updates, for Intel processors.

There are three possible solutions for it.

1. You can add `dis_ucode_ldr` to the kernel parameters to boot into the kernel, and then make it persistent once in by adding it  to `/etc/default/grub` then update-grub.
2. You can boot using the above method once then roll back to a previous version of the microcode package and mark it down, using the following commands

`sudo apt install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1`

Then hold the package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

3. You can update the bios to a version where this issue is fixed. Updating the BIOS is the most recommended and foolproof option in my opinion since it addresses the root cause of the problem. You can find instruction on how to update the BIOS below.

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008859/

All three solutions worked for me, when I tried them once after the other. I hope it helps you out.