# Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS15 9570 - Impossible to reliably suspend/hibernate

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

Sadly I decided to upgrade to 18.04. Now I pass half of my work hours fixing bugs.

Today specialty is: suspend the laptop. 
Last time I tried to suspend my XPS15 9570 I almost burned up my new 2000$ because it was running for 3 hours in my backpack instead of being suspended.

As well documented in a lot of threads, out of the box 18.04 on a lot of laptop is unable to suspend the laptop. There are official bug reports 3 years old, no solution or fix whatsoever. It will simply wake up after 5 seconds or when you close the lid (very sneaky, very dangerous).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574120
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1786094

I tried **everything**, the only solution that works for me is the one reported here:

[Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close)

that is changing the grub config to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"`

With this change the system actually suspend properly, but when it wakes up wi-fi/bluetooth adapter are completely dead, not even a reboot is able to bring them back.

Something similar is reported here

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201469

and maybe here
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1514836

I also tried to hibernate, without any success (the system will simply shut down). This is probably my fault since I'm missing a swap partition.

After passing the whole day reading and trying solution I decide to open this thread. My question is simple:
how can I, end user in 2019, suspend my laptop without shutting down wifi or other key components of my HW?

I know that I sound arrogant but I lost one day of work on a standard feature that should not pose any problem.

Thank you for any assistance, I hop you had a better day than mine.

Comment: I bought a XPS13 with 18 preinstalled and am disgusted by 18. I used to work on 16, it worked fine, but Ubuntu 18 full of regressions. I hate it and wish I had known this in advance...

Answer (score 8):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with

> sudo vim /etc/default/grub

make sure that the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line has the following items:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2015\" acpi_backlight=vendor mem_sleep_default=deep"

or

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 mem_sleep_default=deep"

Insert `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2015\` will not change screen brightness.

update grub:

> sudo update-grub

reboot
after computer has restarted, try suspending to see if the laptop wakes up normally

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Likewise adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 mem_sleep_default=deep"` and rebooting seems to do the trick, this is ona 9570 running "bios" 1.11.2

Answer (score 2):

First answer option 2

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 mem_sleep_default=deep"

did it for me.   XPS 15 9570  Ubuntu 18.04

I did not need to edit that /lib/systemd/system-sleep script.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across OP's option a few days ago:

> that is changing the grub config to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet
>   splash mem_sleep_default=deep"`

but laptop would wake up instantly.

I reactivated this old script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd` and then it worked:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

The screen briefly flashes once while suspending but it's worked 100% since I activated kernel's `deep` sleep parameter.