# Lenovo Ideapad 720s consuming a lot of power during suspend [18.04]

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, lenovo, battery

I have a new Lenovo Ideapad 720s (intel) running Ubuntu 18.04. Most everything works well, except it appears to be using an inordinately large amount of power while suspended. For example, power will drain from 100% to 80% overnight, and will go to zero by day 2 of suspend. I have Googled the hell out of this issue, and cannot find a solution. I have TLP installed, powertop installed, and have checked if I can suspend to disk (hybernate) instead (I can't). I really would like to be able to suspend with this guy as I hate having to shutdown and then go through cryptdisk password and then desktop login password ever. single. time. I. want. to. use. my. computer.

Any ideas at all would be very, very, very greatly appreciated. I honestly don't even know what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else correct me, as I am about to appear foolish indeed.
When I 'suspend' my Desktop, it is very fast to wake and resume.  Of course, my desktop is connected to a power source.  Is not your laptop capable of the same?  IE; plug it in whilst suspended! ????

Comment: While this is technically possible, it belies the point of having a laptop, which is mobile and can travel with you. For example, if I was on a flight, I would very much like to put the laptop into suspend so that I can quickly start back up whenever I have a moment during the trip.

Answer (score 0):

I *finally* found an answer in this [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1036122#1036122). Basically, suspend was configured as "idleS2" instead of "deep". I applied the fix from the other thread (adding a line to grub config options), and all is good. Just suspended for several hours with less than 1% battery drain. Hallelujah!