# Battery overheating and drain while suspended!

Tags: power-management, battery, overheating, acpi, tlp

I have a new ASUS ZenBook UX533F with Ubuntu 19.04. Initially, battery life was excellent, heat was low and suspend worked properly.

I was trying to find a way to limit the battery charge to 80% to extend the life of the battery, so:

1. I installed `tlp` and `tlp-rdw`.

However, `sudo tlp-stat --battery` reported that I could not set thresholds for charging:

```
natacpi    = inactive (no kernel support)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (laptop not supported)
tp-smapi   = inactive (laptop not supported)
```

Foolishly, I thought that if I could get kernel support for `natacpi`, I would be able to use this feature, so I did:

2. `sudo apt install acpi-call-dkms` - had read somewhere that this would make the feature work.

When I did that, it told me that it needed to "register" something on the BIOS or UEFI (I did not understand what it meant - I saw the word "MOK" somewhere).

It was too late!

Now, my battery life is much lower, my laptop is constantly overheating and it even produces a high level of heat when it is suspended.

I have already verified that the laptop enters suspend:

`Oct 03 11:21:15 myuser kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)`

Did I ruin my new laptop? Somebody help!!!

Comment: You have 's2idle' sleep mode activated instead of 'deep' sleep. There is a [bug with the s2idle mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1808957). You better switch to the deep sleep mode. Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close)