# Save more energy on Ubuntu + XPS13 in Standby mode

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, battery, xps

I remember on my old Macbook, when I closed the lid, I could open it one week later and it lost a few percentage points of energy over the week (about 10%).

When I do this with my `xps13`, the first problem is, that it doesn't really go to standby, when I close the lid, so I have to do the process manually.

1. Click the lock symbol:
   [image]
2. Now the power LED is still on:
   [image]
3. So I have to move the mouse again to end the black screen then press the pause button
   [image]

As I took the picture I had 66% again, but it was at 55%, so I have lost 45% of energy in only ONE night in standby! So whats the trick here? Is there a feature to keep the energy in standby mode for 1-2 weeks or is this not possible with Ubuntu?

PS: I have also to mention that on Ubuntu I have closed ALL programs before activating the standby mode. On the Macbook I had about 10-20 programs open before just closing the lid and putting it to standby automatically.

From comments:

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

results in

```
[s2idle] deep
```

Comment: Thing to consider: using the lock option does not mean you actually suspend/hibernate your system. "the first problem is, that it doesn't really go to standby," so you answered your own question: there is no power saving. 2 things that consume power on lock: USB and WIFI/BT. WIFI/BT. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close seems to answer your issue in more detail

Comment: Please provide the output of the following command: `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` (in reference to the comment by @Rinzwind above).

Comment: @Rinzwind this is the output `[s2idle] deep`

Comment: @saitam add it next time to the question. I did that for you this time but next time I might not see it ;-)  what kernel do you have. 5.3 seems to fix a lot of your issues. Oh and I see conflicting ideas: "s2idle" is active and intended but you probably should have "deep"active.

Comment: @saitam see if the answers fixes it for you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case "s2idle" sleep mode is active and intended but you probably should have "deep" active. There is a [bug with the s2idle mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1808957). This should be fixed with kernel version 5.3. To switch to deep sleep mode, do

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

and reload it with

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot and try suspend again. You can do these from command line:

```
systemctl suspend
```

and/or

```
systemctl hibernate
```