# 20.04 LTS Since upgrade from 19.10 laptop doesn't suspend anymore after lid close

Tags: suspend, power-management, 20.04, acpi, lid

My Lenovo P50 laptop used to suspend nicely when I closed the lid on Ubuntu 19.10. After the upgrade this doesn't work anymore. When I execute the command `sudo systemctl suspend` then the laptop still goes into a very rapid full functional suspend. So something seems to go wrong somewhere in handling the lid close event from acpi.

I'm using gnome-tweak-tools and it has the toggle to suspend on lid close enabled as expected.

I also checked the configuration in /etc/systemd/logind.conf and it seems perfect:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

I haven't found anything noticable in the /var/log/syslog.

The workaround I found is the following:

Create a file called `/etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid-close` with the following content:

```
event=button/lid LID close
action=/etc/acpi/laptop-lid-close.sh
```

And create a file `/etc/acpi/laptop-lid-close.sh` with the following content and gave it execute rights (`chmod +x /etc/acpi/laptop-lid-close.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

systemctl suspend
```

Would be better if this workaround would not be necessary ofcourse

Acpi seems to fire off 'lid close' events as it should, otherwise the workaround would not work.
Also the suspend itself must be working on my laptop as well for the same reason.

Any clues on how to learn why this doesn't work out of the box?

Comment: I had a similar problem -- thanks for posting the solution here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close)

Comment: This solution did NOT survive the upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS. But I have some more problems with gnome sessions crashing when I connect a monitor for example, so I'm not sure yet what's the root cause or causes

Answer (score 3):

I had similar with a fresh UbuntuDDE install. I found answers in various sources (this one is probably the most relevant [Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close)). The issue is the laptop not going into "deep" sleep. Run this command

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

And if you get the result below, then this is the issue.

```
[s2idle] deep
```

To change it, edit your grub file (location: /etc/default/grub) to add this text to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line

```
mem_sleep_default=deep
```

Then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. After reboot, run this again

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

and confirm now that your result is

```
s2idle [deep]
```

Then you should be good to go.

Comment: Good addition and great that it works for you, but in my case it already reports ```s2idle [deep]``` before I changed anything

Comment: maybe you can explicitly mention the location of the grub file: /etc/default/grub

Comment: Did you mean to say "If you do *not* get the result below, then this is the issue"?

Comment: In my case the output is just `[s2idle]` and it doesn't change after editing the grub file.