# Ubuntu studio 20.10 sleep mode stopped working

Tags: suspend, dell, 20.10, ubuntu-studio

I have Ubuntu studio 20.10 installed alongside windows on a Dell precision 5540 laptop. I have been running this setup for a couple of months now and sleep mode has always been working, triggered by lid close, by manual activation from the power menu or when idling for longer periods on battery, as set up in the power management settings.

A couple of weeks ago, the laptop suddenly would not go to sleep anymore. I discovered the issue since it would spin the fans and run hot when transported in a bag from/to work.
When manually starting sleep mode from the power menu, the screen goes black shortly to then resume presenting me with the login screen like after a reboot (only much quicker than a reboot). I am no longer logged in then and my session with all open documents and windows is lost.

I had the issue resume to normal after a software update but now it has reoccurred and I don't know what to do.
Having a laptop run out of battery because it heats my bag is not particularly useful.
Since I am not a very experienced user, I would appreciate any detailed guidance to find the root of the evil...

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue after the update that was applied to my system today (Ubuntu 20.04 / Lenovo Legion Y540).
When closing the lid, it looks like the laptop only goes partially into suspend mode. The screen goes off, the wifi  goes off and maybe some other things as well, but the keyboard stays illuminated and the fan keeps running.

I tried different suggestions which I found on the net like:

[Suspend on lid close not working](https://github.com/pop-os/beta/issues/96)

and

[20-04-lts-since-upgrade-from-19-10-laptop-doesnt-suspend-anymore-after-lid-clos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239397)

but nothing helped.

Then because of this thread
[nvidia-460](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia-460-driver-freezes-randomly-after-resume-from-suspend-hibernate/173818) ,

I changed the nvidia driver from 460 (proprietary, tested) to 465 (proprietary), rebooted and the suspend mode worked again.
I changed the driver via 'Software & Updates' => 'Additional Drivers'.

Maybe worth to try ...

Comment: I was also aware of the fact that the nvidia drivers could cause the issue, but I was not able to install the nvidia-465 version until now. Somehow a couple of days ago, the most recent option for me to choose in driver manager was nvidia-460. But when I tried again after your suggestion, I found the nvidia-465 as a choosable option and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help - now my laptop is finally usable again!