# 20.04 install Lenovo P53 not suspending

Tags: suspend, 20.04, thinkpad

This is a fresh 20.04 install on a [Lenovo ThinkPad P53](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p53_hmm_en.pdf) ([more](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p53-type-20qn-20qq)), with NVIDIA drivers active.  If I run [`systemctl suspend`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemctl.1.html) the screen goes black, then I wind up at the lock screen and need to enter my password. I'm guessing it has something to do with the USB setup.

Suspend/hibernate was working until I did a clean reinstall of 20.04.

What should I try next ?

```
# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \n \l
# uname -srv
Linux 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020
# cat /sys/power/suspend_stats/last_failed_dev 
1-0015
# cat /sys/power/suspend_stats/last_failed_errno 
-110
# cat /sys/power/suspend_stats/last_failed_step
suspend

# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
s2idle [deep]

# lspci 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0d)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106GLM [Quadro RTX 3000 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
2c:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
52:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
54:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
55:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

From `dmesg`:

```
[ 2856.919370] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 2856.928663] Freezing user space processes  .. (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 2856.930966] OOM killer disabled.
[ 2856.930966] Freezing remaining freezable tasks .. (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 2856.932056] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2856.932562] wlp82s0: deauthenticating from 3c:37:86:b4:a3:82 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2857.135985] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 2857.135986] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 2857.379986] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 2857.379988] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 2857.624037] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 2857.624038] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 2857.664332] PM: dpm_run_callback(): elan_suspend+0x0/0x110 [elan_i2c] returns -110
[ 2857.664334] PM: Device 1-0015 failed to suspend: error -110
[ 2857.664335] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[ 2857.677683] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 2857.848206] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[ 2857.861202] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 2862.131228] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[ 2862.131599] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[ 2862.131901] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[ 2862.133077] OOM killer enabled.
[ 2862.133080] Restarting tasks .. done.
[ 2862.177572] PM: suspend exit
[ 2862.177619] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[ 2862.182376] Filesystems sync: 0.004 seconds
[ 2862.235281] Freezing user space processes .. (elapsed 0.149 seconds) done.
[ 2862.384665] OOM killer disabled.
[ 2862.384667] Freezing remaining freezable tasks .. (elapsed 0.890 seconds) done.
[ 2863.274911] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2863.479963] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 2863.479964] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 2863.723961] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 2863.723962] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 2863.967936] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 2863.967937] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 2864.008218] PM: dpm_run_callback(): elan_suspend+0x0/0x110 [elan_i2c] returns -110
[ 2864.008225] PM: Device 1-0015 failed to suspend: error -110
[ 2864.008229] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[ 2864.022549] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 2864.192636] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[ 2864.205101] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 2865.243333] OOM killer enabled.
[ 2865.243335] Restarting tasks ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find some help from this older post related to Ubuntu 18.04.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1036122/152964

I'm facing the same issue and through this post, one thing got cleared - that my system isn't going into "deep" sleep but "s2idle" sleep even though the output of:

```
$cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle shallow [deep]
```

But, as you can clearly see below, my system still goes in "s2idle" mode:

```
$systemctl suspend
```

```
$ sudo journalctl | grep "PM: suspend" | tail -2
May 30 13:16:56 n5110 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
May 30 13:16:56 n5110 kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

I'm still trying to work it out, tell me if it fixes your problem.
Btw, my system is Dell Inspiron n5110 with Nvidia Graphics

**Updated (Solved):**

Ok, in my case the culprit was "bbswitch" module and I got my issue resolved by disabling it. Installed it via package bbswitch-dkms to hard block/permanently disable my Nvidia graphics to keep my system a bit more cooler.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to my external keyboard and mouse. I removed all peripherals (even though this had worked for months) and reinstalled. Viola, suspend works, but when I woke the laptop up it goes to a black screen.  I tried the known fixes and nothing helped - so I am suspicious that something is up with the new fw level and my laptop. @sanket I +1 you...
Thanks for the answer....

Comment: # Update
I finally gave up and did a factory reset of everything. The firmware had been updated and thats when things went sideways. So I formatted the disks, set the bios to factory defaults, and then I found this link about installing Ubuntu on the Lenovo P53 [https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/LenovoThinkpad_P53_P73_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_Installation_v1.0.pdf] . The **OS Optimized Defaults** was _Enabled_ . It has been set to _False_ and now things seem to have returned to normal. Now to load Virtualbox and possibly the Nvidia drivers and see what happens...