# Sleep mode drains battery very fast

Tags: 18.04, suspend, battery

Battery drains in about 10 hours when the computer is asleep with Ubuntu 18.04, it is a lenovo y520 (7700hq, 1060 with bumblebee).
When I tested no USB devices were plugged in, actually nothing was plugged in.

The sleep mode is s2 - deep. I am not interested in hibernation (it is quite slow and takes a lot of space).
In windows and Mac OS (hackintosh) sleep mode uses 1 or 2% of battery in a day.

Comment: Instead of unplugging USB make sure buses are powered off. Also make sure Wake on LAN is turned off. On phone so don't haven't links handy here.

Comment: Wake on LAN as in a bios setting ? If yes, it is disabled, trying to check usb status right now

Comment: It.might be possible for Linux to override the BIOS setting but I believe it would respect it unless forced. (Still on phone)

Comment: Ok, so I tried cutting the usb power, but from what I understand, for newer kernels "suspend" does not work anymore. So I checked if the values in "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power" are correct, and they seem to be. Not sure if it's the right way though

Comment: Any suggestion is appreciated. I noticed the cpu isn't really going to sleep. Voltage going through it even if the machine is in sleep mode.

Comment: I've been grappling with that problem for a long time and even offered a bounty on it once: https://askubuntu.com/questions/828486/systemd-suspends-system-but-upon-resume-kernel-then-enters-sleep-and-wake-up

Comment: Yes. The CPU's being awake when they should have been sleeping problem was ~2 years ago. Now I'm on Kernel `4.13.0-36` and problem still persisted over the 2 years. I look back at issue every few months but all three of my laptops are plugged in 24/7 so it's not that big of a deal for me.

Comment: So, I guess you switched kernels ? Sleep is extremely important to me, allows me to move around without waiting for the startup and launching my suite. It's disappointing to have this issue.

Comment: Hey, I still face this issue, have you fixed it with a newer kernel version maybe >

Comment: Sorry I don't follow up on this issue as my laptops are plugged in 24/7 it's low priority.

Comment: Sure, wasn't really expecting a response so thanks :D

Comment: Due to guilty conscience I posted an answer :D

Comment: on a lenovo x1, didn't have issues with this before, but recently (last month or so?) I've noticed power drain in sleep that I wasn't seeing before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After resuming from suspend, use this command in the terminal:

```
journalctl -b | grep -i "should not be sleeping"
```

If you see this:

```
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Oct 21 07:20:18 alien kernel:  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
```

It could mean when you suspended the CPU's were not put to sleep as per his bounty Q&A a couple of years ago: [systemd suspends system but upon resume kernel then enters sleep and wake-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828486/systemd-suspends-system-but-upon-resume-kernel-then-enters-sleep-and-wake-up)

If so, I'm sad to report the problem persists to this day on my newest laptop just as it did on that older laptop.

---

### Problem since 2012?

This old email chain: [Re: Kernel stops at "PM: Preparing system for mem sleep", never makes it to "Freezing user space processes ... "](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-acpi/msg37409.html) has a similar problem.

From my log file today:

```
Oct 21 13:48:15 alien kernel: PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Oct 21 13:48:16 alien acpid[964]: client 1171[0:0] has disconnected
Oct 21 13:48:32 alien kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
```

- Line 1 is normal
- Line 2 is abnormal and linked to old X11 crash bugs
- Line 3 is occurs after resuming but should have happened as part of suspend.

Some other interesting points is it often takes 5 to 8 seconds to suspend when it should be about 1 second. This bug is reported in many places too.

---

If you don't have the same problem in the previous sections and, your laptop stays warm when suspended, then your fix maybe here: [Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1036122#1036122)

Comment: Yep, I get the same output :|

Comment: Is it the same thing for 16.04 ?

Comment: Yes. The logs above were generated this morning under Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Maybe you saw this coming, but what about 14.04 ?

Comment: According to the first link, I believe 14.04 works OK but can't confirm it today as that laptop needs some TLC to get boot working again. However with email chain I discovered with kernel developers and just posted in this answer it may have been broken for some in Ubuntu 14.04 all the way back to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Just so I know, does this mean there's no difference between sleep and idle for the cpu or does it chill out a bit ?

Comment: Hey, umm, more great news, I tried switching to windows for a day, then I find out not even windows' sleep is working anymore, is it related to linux, (bootloader more specifically)

Comment: I've done a frsh install of windows, sleep behaves now just like ubuntu, it;s ridiculous. How do I get rid of this...?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Do you suppose out-of-order-execution  could be to blame for https://askubuntu.com/questions/828486/kernel-suspends-too-quickly-upon-resume-continues-suspend-tasks ? I updated my answer there with a way you could test that.

Comment: @ElderGeek I quickly read your answer revisions. I'm not sure that's the culprit but am hoping the bug report filed yeseterday will give answers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1825636

Answer (score 1):

On my old computer, I solved my suspend issues by adjusting some settings in the motherboard BIOS.

For my hardware:

On the "Advanced" page in BIOS under "CPU configuration", I set "**Enhanced Alt State**" to **ENABLED**, and under "ACPI Settings" , I set "**Suspend to RAM**" to **AUTO** and "**ACPI table**" to **ENABLED**.

After I made these changes, I could suspend my PC.

***Note: BIOS settings and motherboard firmware vary by manufacturer and model***