# Computer shutting down as if the adapter was unplugged

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, battery

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot. Recently, I've noticed that my laptop would just power off suddenly as if you had a desktop computer that was unplugged. No, it doesn't go through the proper steps of shutting down.

Today, something related occurred when I closed the lid to put my laptop to sleep. When I opened my lid, my laptop was already turned off.

I am not sure whether it's a hardware issue or now. After reading around, it is suggested that I look at var/log/syslog. Below you will see the period in which I closed my laptop's lid. I can't seem to diagnose the problem

[image: syslog part 1]
[image: syslog part 2]

To add some details about my laptop, it's a dell inspiron 13 with dual boot windows that I rarely use. Also, I have an internal battery and I had the original battery replaced in best buy sometime in July since the old one was just drained. I got the new battery from Amazon. Is there anything I can do from my side to figure out what the problem is?

Help very much appreciated.

Edit: According to the comment below, I was suggested to try `acpi -abi`:.

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 17%, 00:38:50 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 3950 mAh, last full capacity 3692 mAh = 93%
Adapter 0: off-line
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100095/discussion-on-question-by-user1237300-computer-shutting-down-as-if-the-adapter-w).

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple issues to solve here but this is one thing to try:

Use the command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action
```

If the result is not `suspend` then use the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
```

This way when your battery is critically low you won't loose your work due to a shutdown. Then plug in your laptop and resume from suspend. You don't want your laptop left unplugged in suspend mode too long because the battery will still eventually die and you will be left in a state as if an abrupt power off had been performed.

A fully-charged battery might only last two days with laptop suspended and unplugged:

- [Sleep mode drains battery very fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072066/sleep-mode-drains-battery-very-fast)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

User normally operates laptop from battery, not AC power. Battery was replaced in July. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L3G5G1X/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L3G5G1X)

`acpi -abi` will give some indication about the status of the battery and AC adapter.

We need to reset the power management unit in the laptop. With the AC adapter unplugged, let the machine power itself off when on battery, then press the power button and hold it down for 15 seconds. This will reset the power management. Then charge the battery and retest for the problem.