# Laptop suspends too early after uplugging the power cable

Tags: suspend, laptop, battery, timeout

I'm having this irritating problem, stated in the title on my Lenovo T14 with Ubuntu 20.04 (but had it also on ASUS Zen and Ubuntu 18.04).
I have "Automatic suspend" set to 20 minutes "When on battery power" and disabled for "Plugged in" in the Gnome Settings.
If I don't press any key, nor click/move mouse for 15 minutes and then unplug power cable, the laptop suspends in 5 minutes.
If I don't press any key, nor click/move mouse for >= 20 minutes and then unplug power cable, the laptop suspends immediately.

I changed the "dconf-editor" --> `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/use-time-for-policy` to `false` as suggested on [Laptop immediately suspends when going onto battery power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6491/laptop-immediately-suspends-when-going-onto-battery-power), or https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1614861, but it doesn't seem to work.

Even if it did, wouldn't it disable timeout-triggered suspending completely? I still want it to suspend after 20 minutes "on battery power", which should be counted since unplugging of the power cable even if the computer was idle at that point.

Any suggestions?

Similar threads:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85251/my-laptop-shuts-down-every-time-i-unplug-it

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/427629

Comment: What condition or how old is your battery? Check out the answer here that starts with **There could be multiple issues** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181909/computer-shutting-down-as-if-the-adapter-was-unplugged

Comment: I bought this laptop 3 weeks ago, so the battery is *fairly new*. Besides, this has been happening on the other, different laptop too.