# Which devices drain battery in laptop suspend mode?

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, battery

My laptop drains much energy during suspend mode and I'd like to identify what part is draining energy.
**Is it possible to list devices that are still active in suspend mode?** Ideally a command could just output energy consumption by the device the moment before the suspend mode is reached. It would be great if somebody had experience with this.

*(I am wondering specifically about this point. Other reasons for battery drain mentioned in other threads I found were not applicable: Display switches off correctly; system enters deep sleep; battery drain not existent in Windows; hibernation has no battery drain; `dmesg`, `pm-suspend.log` and `analyze_suspend.py` show no error messages; `/proc/acpi/wakeup` all disabled.)*

Comment: For many people suspend doesn't work fully: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072066/sleep-mode-drains-battery-very-fast

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David I run Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I actually get the same error msg as the top reply mentioned "parent cpu1 should not be sleeping" but there seems to be no workaround. My thought was it'd be useful to see a list of devices that fail to sleep. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please ask on [unix.se] as Linux Mint is off-topic here