# Deep sleep not working

Tags: suspend

The battery of my laptop drains very fast when in suspend mode (in 8 hours, it goes from 100% almost to zero). It turned out that deep sleep is not used by default:

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle] deep
```

I tried

```
echo 'deep' > /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

after which everything looks good:

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]
```

But now the laptop does not wake up from suspend mode anymore. When trying to wake up the laptop by the power button (other keys or mouse do not do anything), my keyboard backlight turns on but the screen remains black; rebooting the laptop by holding the power button is the only thing I can do. Also, after the reboot, the suspend mode is back to s2idle:

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle] deep
```

What can I try to make the deep sleep work correctly?

(I have dual booted Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.10 on Acer Aspire 5.)

EDIT:
Following dvs.spy's answer, I can permanently set the deep sleep as the default suspend action. But the laptop does not wake up from a deep sleep. When trying to wake it, the keyboard backlight turns on and I can hear the fans but the screen remains black; reboot is the only option I can see. So, my main question at this moment is:

**What can I do so that my laptop wakes up from a deep sleep?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sleep mode drains battery very fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072066/sleep-mode-drains-battery-very-fast)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Typing `journalctl -b | grep -i "should not be sleeping"
' produces an empty output.

Comment: OK. However, deep sleep has never worked for me and many others as well. It is annoying on one hand but on the other hand the laptop is always plugged in 24/7. It is suspended / resumed a few times a day and that works fine even though deep sleep doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your Linux power management settings are being overridden by other configurations. I had the same issue in Lenovo while using dual boot along with Windows. You can try the following steps:

[+] Edit your GRUB configuration file by running: **sudo nano /etc/default/grub**

[+] Find the line that starts with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** and add **mem_sleep_default=deep** to the list of options. It should look something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

[+] Save the file and update GRUB by running: **sudo update-grub**

[+] Run the following commands to update your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

I hope this will work in your system as well. If not, please try the below command and share the error message that you get:

```
dmesg | grep -i acpi
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After following your suggestions, `deep' remains as the default suspend mode (instead of s2idle) even after restart. But my laptop still cannot wake up from deep sleep. When trying to wake it, the keyboard backlight turns on and I can hear the fans but the screen remains black; reboot is the only option I can see. As such, the deep sleep is of no use. As s2idle is useless as well (because of the battery drain), turning off the laptop (instead of suspending) seems to be my only choice. This is not good...